# How to create and print a document from web app

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ms-word

Building an mvc 3 asp app.

One of the features of an app I am building is the ability to add a paragraph of text to a document template, then print it.  By templated I mean there will be a couple paragraphs of legal blah blah that must be on each letter, and the letter will be printed on company letterhead, so the spacing needs to be set.

This is an internal app to be used by about 120 people, so it is very possible for multiple people to be accessing the template at the same time.  However, the the user will not have the ability to alter the template or save it, just to add a paragraph of text, then print it.

My first thought was to Word 2010, or specifically the new Office Web Apps.  However it looks like this would require installing and licensing on the web server, and the boss aint going for that.

Second option I researched is the kendo Editor,  I have it displaying on the view, but I can't figure out how to make portions of it read only.

So I am looking for some suggestions of other ways to do this.  My fall back will be to do it in reporting services, but this is my last resort, because I want to keep it integrated in my app if possible.

Comment: Is your concern about installing and licensing working with the document or doing the printing?

Comment: This was 3 years ago.  I ended up using SSRS. Thanks, merry Christmas!